# Change all examples of Tax to VAT?

Tags: tax, magento2.3.3, vat

I'm trying to change all uses of the word '**Excl. Tax**' to '**Excl. VAT**' as I'm building a UK site.
I found 3 examples of how to do this but which is the right way?

> 1. Change every use of 'Tax' to 'Vat' in  /vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/layout/{checkout_cart_index.xml}
>      & {checkout_index_index.xml}.
> 2. Add a translation to a en_GB file / not too sure on how to do this
> 3. Install a language pack - composer require cubewebsites/magento2-language-en-gb:*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Following Way..
it is best way to translate using language pack

> composer require
>   mageplaza/magento-2-english-united-kingdom-language-pack:dev-master 
>   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB 
>  php bin/magento
>   indexer:reindex php bin/magento cache:clean 
> php bin/magento
>   cache:flush

if this language pack in file not available then you can add simple like this way..

```
'Excl. Tax','Excl. VAT'
```

Comment: - cubewebsites/magento2-language-en-gb 100.1.7 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12, 100.1.13, 100.1.14, 100.1.15, 100.1.16, 100.1.17, 
100.1.18].

Comment: @Eddie i have updated my answer you can try this way. Ref:https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-english-united-kingdom-language-pack.html

Comment: your updated answer has worked apart from the very last part of the order process in order summary it says 'Excl. Tax' Instead of 'Excl. VAT'. I'm sure this is the only place now though

Comment: Just seen that in the admin there is a button marked 'daten neuladen' I think its reload in German. That has happened since installing the mageplaza language pack.